# Minify inline javascript in magento 2.1 EE

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, minified-js, minify

I found a solution to minify javascript using the following link

https://gist.github.com/lewisp6/b7c50b4d82ef4d3d5d6dc888e8d1bdba

At what path should I place this script?

Comment: Minify js using gulpfile.js ? options in system configuration for minify js or css

Comment: Yes, I did from admin configurations but in Gtmetrix it is showing to minify the js.
I have inline javascript also.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Path of **gulpfile.php**

```
app/code/frontend/Vendor/theme/gulpfile.js
```

> You Can Install Gulp and its Sass Preprocessor :-

[Install Gulp and its Sass preprocessor](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/gulp-sass.html)

Comment: https://github.com/subodha/magento-2-gulp